# How to get twitter's user Access Token?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using https://twitteroauth.com/ in my some PHP pages. I want to get user access token and access secret token. I got my answer on this page: [How to get user Access Token and Access Secret with the Twitter API using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549383/how-to-get-user-access-token-and-access-secret-with-the-twitter-api-using-php)

After replacing my consumer key and secret consumer key on both pages. I upload it on my server but then I got the following error when I open twitter-go.php

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception `'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException'` with message 

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash> 
    <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
    <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
</hash> '
in `/home/mediahyp/public_html/tweetme/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php:138` 

Stack trace: 

#0 /home/mediahyp/public_html/tweetme/twitter-go.php(13): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->oauth('oauth/request_t...', Array) 
#1 {main} thrown in /home/mediahyp/public_html/tweetme/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 138
```

Can anyone tell me what is this error about? Am I missing something or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://twittercommunity.com/t/desktop-applications-only-support-the-oauth-callback-value-oob-oauth-request-token/252/2

> The new interface simplifies this: if you provide a placeholder callback URL in the field for it in your application detail screen, it allows you to use dynamic callbacks. So just go ahead and put a placeholder in there (doesn't have to be the actual dynamic/runtime callback you use) and you'll be able to use other forms of auth.
>
> When no placeholder is presented, the application is locked to OOB mode.

Comment: A note - "twitteroauth.com Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value" in Google finds this as the top result.